# How to make observable to repeat

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have a code that emits a new values :

```
function newValues(): Observable<any> {
    const data$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});

    setInterval((x) => {
       data$.next(this.getNewData());
    }, 1000);

   return data$.asObservable();
}
```

so this way by subscribing to `newValues().subscribe()` I can receive a new values all the time.

But I think it is not the best way of doing this so I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52019214/415078) and so my code became like this:

```
function newValues(): Observable<any> {
    const data$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});

    defer(() => data$.next(this.getNewData()))
      .pipe(
       repeatWhen(notifications => notifications.pipe(delay(1000)))
     );

   return data$.asObservable();
}
```

However it is seems like the code not working now, after receiving the first value no emissions is taking place.

Any ideas how to fix?

**UPDATE:**
@evantha suggest to use interval for that use case, I just wonder does that mean that `defer....repeatWhen....delay` won't work for that use-case?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [interval](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/interval) function.

```
    function newValues(): Observable {
      return interval(1000).pipe(mapTo(getNewData()));
    }
```

you may subscribe to it like this

```
    const mySubscription = newValues().subscribe(r => {
      console.log(r);
    });
```

and when you do not need it anymore make sure to unsubscribe it to avoid any memory leaks.

```
    mySubscription.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: any ideas why it is does not work with `defer` as per my example?

Comment: the thing with Observables is, they won't get executed until you subscribe. when you say `newValues().subscribe()`, you are subscribing to the `data$.asObservable()`.  That won't execute `defer....repeatWhen....delay` observable. you can simply test this if you subscribe to  `defer....repeatWhen....delay` inside `newvalues` function.  But do not do that as you can't unsubscribe from it thus causing memory leaks.

Comment: see this working example with `defer....repeatWhen....delay`: [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ync6cl?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 1):

I think your question contains some points which are different one from each other.

**First point: get a sequence of values (i.e. create a stream)**

In the first code snippet you define a function `newValues()` which returns an Observable which will emit a sequence of values, each value being calculated by the function `getNewData()` called every 1000 ms. To do so you create a `BehaviorSubject` and then call `next` on it with an interval.

If this is what you want, probably the use of rxjs `interval` function is the right way to go as suggested by @evantha. It is simpler and clearer, at least in my opinion.

**Second point: why the second snippet does not work**

The reason is simple. You call the function `defer` but you do not do anything with the value it returns, rather you simply return the `BehaviorSubject` you just created which, by its nature, returns the starting value and nothing more, unless somebody calls `next` on it, which does not happen in the second snippet.

**Third point: use repeatWhen to generate a repetition of values**

The use of `repeatWhen` to generate a repetition is a much more nuanced case, and I suggest you to [read the documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/repeatWhen). I wish to highlight only one thing. `repeatWhen` enters in action when its source Observable `complete`s. And when it `complete`s, `repeatWhen` makes sure that the same source Observable is repeated as soon as the Observable returned by the function passed to `repeatWhen` as parameter emits. You can not easily imagine to have a `BehaviorSubject` as source for `repeatWhen` since you normally do not `complete` a `Subject`. The addition of `delay` makes the case even more complicated.

The example where both `delay` and `repeatWhen` are used refers to a specific use case: polling a resource using an async function, for instance polling a remote system using an hppt call. In this case you may want to use a combination of `delay` and `repeatWhen` to avoid having overlapping calls. But this is a very specific requirement.