# Angular ChangeDetectorRef render live data

Tags: angular, typescript, change-detector-ref

I am trying to get live data on angular basic component.

What I expect:
HTML rendering auto incremented each 1 second (i.e.: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ..etc.)

What I got:
HTML rendering: 0 then 1. (incremented once then stopped)

Stackblitz url for demonstration (apologize if url not valid, first time sharing my code):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-material-jdjcjp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

My code:

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, combineLatest, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  item = 0;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    timer(1000)
      .pipe(
        tap(() => {
          this.item++;
          this.cdr.markForCheck();
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: i think you want interval not timer `interval(1000)`

Answer (score 0):

Use RxJs [Interval](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/interval) instead of timer

```js
interval(1000)  // emit every 1000 milliseconds
      .pipe(
        tap(() => {
          this.item++;
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
```

Comment: I used interval but not that way thx for help.

Comment: @AhmadBarutchi, what you used is the window `setInterval()` method, this is different from RxJs `Interval` operator, please make sure that you understand the difference, and when to use which? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69176940/setinterval-or-rxjs-interval-which-one-to-use

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
ngOnInit() {
    return setInterval(() => {
          this.item++;
          this.cdr.markForCheck();
    }, 1000);
}
```